# How to run following code in rails using Cron ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was looking at railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/168-feed-parsing?view=asciicast where the author is pulling the rss feed in the database through rails console by typing

```
FeedEntry.update_from_feed("http://asciicasts.com/episodes.xml")
```

now this is working fine for the first time but how to do this every 24 hours ? How to use cron here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `whenever` [gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to simplify the task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whenever` gem as @dimuch said, but also you can run cron with this command:

```
$ rails runner 'FeedEntry.update_from_feed("http://asciicasts.com/episodes.xml")'
```

Comment: so how to set cron run of 12 or 24 hours with rails runner ? thanks

Comment: Have you ever using `cron`? If not then type `man 5 crontab` and read about using `crontab` file.